# Vuejs populate input fields value on a element select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am not sure if I am terming this correctly. I have a very simple vuejs application (I just started learning vue a couple of days ago, so my knowledge of vue is really limited).

I have a input field which acts as a search box. When we feed some text input, it triggers `v-on:blur` event to call a function. It then sets the suggestions which are displayed just below the searchbox.

What I am trying to achieve is, when any of those anchor tags are clicked (from the search suggestions), two new input boxes should be automatically populated with the values from the search suggestions.

```
{name: 'Some Name', state: 'Some State'}
```

A very simple and stripped version of the code is as https://jsfiddle.net/dfhpj08g/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    suggestions: [],
    showSuggestions: false,
  },
  methods: {
    suggest() {
      // this is dynamically generated via ajax
      this.suggestions = [{
          name: 'A',
          state: 'OH'
        },
        {
          name: 'B',
          state: 'OR'
        },
      ];
      this.showSuggestions = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-on:blur="suggest" placeholder="search">
  <div v-show="showSuggestions">
    <span>Did you mean</span>
    <li v-for="s in suggestions">
      <a href="#">
        {{s.name}} - ({{s.state}})
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="state">
</div>
```

Comment: *A very simple and stripped version of the code* - **should be in the question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to insert the values into your name and state fields, I would suggest using `v-model` on them and declaring the corresponding data in your component. In that way, you can simply set them using `this.name` and `this.state`:

```
data: {
  suggestions: [],
  showSuggestions: false,
  name: '',
  state: ''
},
```

Use `v-model` to bind `name` and `state` data to your input elements:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" v-model="name">
<input type="text" name="state" placeholder="state" v-model="state">
```

You can bind a click handler to each of the `<a>` elements, so that you will can pass the index of the clicked suggestion. This will allow you to do `this.suggestion[i]` to retrieve the data:

```
<li v-for="(s, i) in suggestions" v-bind:key="i">
  <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="suggestionSelected(i)">
    {{s.name}} - ({{s.state}})
  </a>
</li>
```

Then, in your methods, you can create a new function `suggestionSelected`, which accepts the index of the suggestion as `i`. In that way, you can use the bracket syntax to access the selected suggestion:

```
suggestionSelected(i) {
  this.name = this.suggestions[i].name;
  this.state = this.suggestions[i].state;
}
```

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    suggestions: [],
    showSuggestions: false,
    name: '',
    state: ''
  },
  methods: {
    suggest() {
      // this is dynamically generated via ajax
      this.suggestions = [{
          name: 'A',
          state: 'OH'
        },
        {
          name: 'B',
          state: 'OR'
        },
      ];

      this.showSuggestions = true;
    },
    suggestionSelected(i) {
      this.name = this.suggestions[i].name;
      this.state = this.suggestions[i].state;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-on:blur="suggest" placeholder="search">
  <div v-show="showSuggestions">
    <span>Did you mean</span>
    <li v-for="(s, i) in suggestions" v-bind:key="i">
      <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="suggestionSelected(i)">
        {{s.name}} - ({{s.state}})
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" v-model="name">
  <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="state" v-model="state">

</div>
```